# Moving files in Yosmite doesn't move all the files

Tags: finder, macos

I am having the weirdest problem since upgrading to OSX Yosemite.

If I select a bunch (hundreds) of files and try to move them to a different folder, only a few (under 100, like 86) of the files move. The rest are still left selected in the original folder.

I could not find anyone else experiencing this problem.

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Any other information? Do the folders reside on the same disk? How large are the files? what sort of files, etc.?

Comment: Any file, same hard drive. Just tried it with 500 jpg photos. Only 86 move at a time.

Comment: Did you check the permissions on remaining files?

Comment: Yes, Read & Write.

Comment: How much free space is remaining on your file systems?

Comment: Try copying with the terminal, using cp or rsync and see if it still happens

Comment: Check the file permissions, if they are not correct, open terminal type "sudo su -"       Then type your password and type "chmod -R 770 (file-directory-goes-here)"